# Static Variables in Function after while loop

Tags: php, mysql, static

I have a database abstraction layer in a CMS, and one of the functions is a mysql_fetch_assoc wrapper which includes the connection, query and result logic all in one.

```
_select_row($in_table, $in_what = '*', $in_where = '', 
            $in_arr_params = array(), $in_flags)
{
  // Generates a unique enough name based on query contents.
  $hash = md5($in_table.$in_what.implode((array)$in_arr_params).$in_flags);

  if (!isset($_STATIC))
  {
    static $_STATIC = array();
  }

  if (isset($_STATIC[$hash])
  {
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($_STATIC[$hash]);
  }

  // *snip* SQL logic here, connect -> query -> result *snip*

  $_STATIC[$hash] = $result;
  return mysql_fetch_assoc($_STATIC[$hash]);
}
```

It maintains a static variable so when being used in loops, it can iterate like a standard fetch_assoc call.

```
while (_select_row('mytable')) // Loops all rows
{
  // Do Stuff
}
```

The only problem I'm having is a corner case: if the programmer tries to make the same query again later in the script, it will continue the iteration instead of starting again. I could create a reset function of some sort, or work with a selector function and a results function, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution in which the function would "know" when it was not being called in the same loop, and dump the results. Also, just for efficiency sake I'd like it to dump results when they are done.

Any ideas, or is switching to a select->result model really the only way around this?

Comment: Pass in a parameter to say "do not used cached results"?

Comment: `if (!isset($_STATIC))` kinda defeats the purpose of static variables. You can skip this.

Answer (score 0):

Statics are generally a bad idea, for exactly this sort of reason.

Just pass in an extra parameter, as a reference to a "state" structure that's updated by the function on each iteration.

If you want to get advanced, you could wrap the function in a class, that maintains the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean reset flag to the function to indicate if it is to reset:

```
_select_row($in_table, /* snip a bunch of params */, $reset=FALSE)
{
  // Generates a unique enough name based on query contents.
  $hash = md5($in_table.$in_what.implode((array)$in_arr_params).$in_flags);

  if (!isset($_STATIC))
  {
    static $_STATIC = array();
  }

  if (isset($_STATIC[$hash])
  {
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($_STATIC[$hash]);
  }

  // *snip* SQL logic here, connect -> query -> result *snip*

  $_STATIC[$hash] = $result;
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // If this is a reset, set position to 0
  if ($reset) mysql_data_seek($_STATIC[$hash], 0);
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  return mysql_fetch_assoc($_STATIC[$hash]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted elegant, but you could use debug_backtrace() to figure out where this was called from.

Comment: Having the internals of the function being inelegant isn't so bad, the elegance I'm looking for is for using the function. Like how jQuery has some ugly hacks in it for specific browsers (Looking at you IE), but its actual usage is elegant.

Though if the statement was used in a sub-loop, backtrace might produce the same results anyway; that could also be the expected behaviour.

I'm going to look into this method though, it shows some promise.